# mocha: How to reduce printed time when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I run mocha with `mocha --slow 0 ./test/test.js` to show the time it takes for calls to complete. I'm writing a library that does very async things with another service and response time matters. However some of the calls in my library cause another service to do slow operations like *start*, *stop*, *remove* more time to complete then exist between two consecutive tests. The result is that the printed time for the *remove* test is shown to be longer then the actual time it takes for the call to complete.

```
describe(`stopContainer ${test_name} t:0`, () => {
  it(`should stop the container named ${test_name}`, () => {
    return engine.stopContainer(test_name, {t:0}).should.be.fulfilled
  })
})

// this shows to be much longer than the actual call takes
describe(`removeContainer ${test_name} v:1 `, () => {
  it(`should remove the container named ${test_name} & volumes`, function(done) {
    // needs to wait a second because of engine latency
    this.timeout(5000)
    setTimeout(() => {
      engine.removeContainer(test_name, {v:1}).should.be.fulfilled.and.notify(done);
    }, 1000)
  })
})
```

Prints the following

```
  stopContainer dap_test_container t:0
    ✓ should stop the container named dap_test_container (285ms)
  removeContainer dap_test_container v:1
    ✓ should remove the container named dap_test_container & volumes (1405ms)
```

Obviously the last test took 1000ms less then is reported. But I have to do this all over the place with hundreds of tests and so the reported values become more meaningless as I cannot keep track of which ones are delayed and which are not.

**note** I don't mean to use this as a method of profiling my code, this is just to make my test results more meaningful.

I'd like to reduce the printed time, is there a way with mocha to reduce the printed time manually? Or does mocha provide a better construct for doing this?

Comment: It shows a long time because it takes a long time-integration tests are just that. If you don't want to time an integration test them don't write one-don't do stuff external to what you're actually testing.

Comment: Agreed - why not use e.g. Sinon.js to stub out external calls? Testing external calls are often meaningless as you are essentially just testing that they work "at testing time" without any guarantee they will work a minute later. In stead you could use stubs simulating their expected behaviour ...

Comment: I disagree - you are both assuming a lot on your own. These tests are not part of a production system or anything of the sort. It's just so I can do my daily work.

Also it's interfacing with the docker-engine remote api which has something like 1800 open issues today, not all are bugs, but I'm certainly finding bugs in that "external service" and actively contributing those bug reports back to improve it.

Another point, suggestion these comments are completely reductive to the question.

Comment: @MatUtter : no offense intended. But I do think the highest quality is obtained - also when testing - when observing the separation of concerns principle. So when it makes sense to test an external service I would personally make a test suit for that and otherwise stub it out when testing my own code.

Comment: You're still missing the point. Discussing the principles of TDD & regression testing has nothing with the question. If I wanted to ask about that, I would. I'm not. I'm **experimenting** with using that other services API's. There is a very clear question about **mocha** which both of these responses ignore.

Comment: A good answer can also be to help someone think differently about an applied approach. Besides you did yourself write that you wanted to make your *"...test results more meaningful"* and I think the best way to achieve that is by separating the test suit for the external service and the test suit for your own code in stead of manipulating the combined test time of a mixed test. So maybe the question could have been clearer ....

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, delay in the `before` or `after`.

I made a global called wait

```
global.wait = wait = function(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}
```

And use it in the tests like so

```
describe(`removeContainer ${test_name} v:1 `, () => {

  before('wait for latency', () => wait(1000))

  it(`should remove the container named ${test_name} & volumes`, () => {
    return engine.removeContainer(test_name, {v:1}).should.be.fulfilled;
  })
})
```